# How to filter mapped data with multiple select options in REACT

Tags: reactjs, filter

I created some test data and i need to render based off a select option input. The data that should be the closest match.

For example if i should select option 'java'. Then it should render all people that have that skill.

I had a look at some other solutions online and i couldn't see something that i could apply.

```
export const Employees = [
{
    name: "jane",
    skill: 'java',
    rankgrade: '44.2',
    available:'22/01/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jake",
    skill: 'javascript',
    rankgrade: '43.2',
    available:'22/04/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "kamil",
    skill: 'react',
    rankgrade: '42.2',
    available:'22/11/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "erica",
    skill: 'nexus',
    rankgrade: '38.2',
    available:'22/09/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jasper",
    skill: 'typescript',
    rankgrade: '47.2',
    available:'22/03/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jane",
    skill: 'java',
    rankgrade: '44.2',
    available:'22/01/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jake",
    skill: 'javascript',
    rankgrade: '43.2',
    available:'22/04/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "kamil",
    skill: 'react',
    rankgrade: '42.2',
    available:'22/11/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "erica",
    skill: 'nexus',
    rankgrade: '38.2',
    available:'22/09/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jasper",
    skill: 'typescript',
    rankgrade: '47.2',
    available:'22/03/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jane",
    skill: 'java',
    rankgrade: '44.2',
    available:'22/01/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jake",
    skill: 'javascript',
    rankgrade: '43.2',
    available:'22/04/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "kamil",
    skill: 'react',
    rankgrade: '42.2',
    available:'22/11/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "erica",
    skill: 'nexus',
    rankgrade: '38.2',
    available:'22/09/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
{
    name: "jasper",
    skill: 'typescript',
    rankgrade: '47.2',
    available:'22/03/23',
    doj:'14/04/21'
},
```

]

I was able to create something like this without inputs, how would that be translated to a select option? for reference i am using this as a select option from Ant design library.

```
<Space wrap>
    <Select
      defaultValue="Rank/Grade"
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      
      options={[
        { value: '44.2', label: '44.2' },
        { value: '44.4', label: '44.4' },
        { value: '38.2', label: '38.2' },
      ]}
    />
    
     </Space>



 {Employees.filter(employee => employee.skill  === "javascript" && employee.name != "" && employee.rankgrade != "")
         
         .map(filteredPerson => (
         
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.name}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.rankgrade}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.skill}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.available}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.doj}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                ))}
```

Comment: error Unexpected token, expected "," (39:78)

  37 |       defaultValue="Rank/Grade"
  38 |       style={{ width: 120 }}
> 39 |       onChange={(e) => setSelectedValue(previousState => ({...previousState, e.target.value}))}

Comment: I have handled it with react-select and have posted here https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-brahmagupta-fqzx2p?file=/src/App.js
See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the select option value in a state and pass the selected value to filter

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('')
<Space wrap>
    <Select
      defaultValue="Rank/Grade"
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      value={selectedValue}
      onChange={(e) => setSelectedValue(prev => ({...prev, e.target.value}))}
      
      options={[
        { value: 'java', label: '44.2' },
        { value: 'react', label: '44.4' },
        { value: 'vue', label: '38.2' },
      ]}
    />
    
     </Space>

{Employees.filter(employee => employee.skill  === selectedValue && employee.name != "" && employee.rankgrade != "")
         
         .map(filteredPerson => (
         
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.name}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.rankgrade}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.skill}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.available}</td>
                    <td className="col-lg-2">{filteredPerson.doj}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                ))}
```

Comment: keeps saying  Unexpected token, expected "," for this  e.target.value?

Comment: May be this would work. onChange={(e, newVal) => setSelectedValue(prev => ({...prev, newVal}))}